# node http proxy SSL transparent

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, proxy

In my setup, I have 2 layers of transparent proxies.  When a client makes an SSL request, I wish to have the first proxy it meets simply forward the traffic to another one without attempting to do the handshake with the client.

The setup seems funny, but it is justified in my case - the 2nd proxy registers itself to the first one (through some other service) only occassionally.  It tells the first: "I'm interested in some traffic that looks like_*_*_".  In most cases, the 1st proxy simply does the work.

Can an httpProxy (in node-proxy) proxy SSL requests?  Must I use an httpsProxy (which will then do the handshake with the client)?

Comment: Are you after a MITM proxy (which could look *inside* the connections, provided its clients are configured to trust it) or just the equivalent of a normal HTTPS proxy, just transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do all of this with the existing httpsProxy if you wanted to. Unless you are wanting to use a non-Node proxy or proxy to a different server, I can't see what you would gain by having two.

Simply add the required the logging/signing logic to the existing httpsProxy.

Typically, I use https on the proxy to both restrict the number of open ports and to remove the need to do https on all of the Node servers running. You can also add Basic Auth using http-basic library too.

See my example code: https://github.com/TotallyInformation/node-proxy-https-example/blob/master/proxy.js

EDIT 2012-05-15: Hmm, after some thought, I wonder if you shouldn't be looking at something like [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to do what you want rather than Node?

Comment: sorry, I have clarified my question.  I think you may have understood it wrong.  I realize that my existing httpsProxy could do what I had mentioned before - but that wasn't the point.

Comment: In your example, it's the connection between the client and the proxy that's over HTTPS (and then perhaps the connection to the target server too), isn't it? I could see the point of that, but that doesn't make sense in a transparent proxy context.

Comment: I do not believe that you can do this with Node Proxy because you are really setting up a server to listen over a specific proxy. The server either has to listen on http or https. If the latter, then it will do the handshake. If the former it will not understand the https that the browser is sending.

Answer (score 2):

(For reference, I've already made some of those points in [my answer to your similar question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/371527/47187).)

- If you are after a MITM proxy (that is, a proxy that can look inside the SSL content by using its own certificates, which can work provided the clients are configured to trust them), it will hardly be fully transparent, since you will at least have to configure its clients to trust its certificates.

  In addition, unless all your client use the server name indication extension, the proxy itself will be unable to determine reliably which host to issue its certificate for (something that a normal HTTPS proxy would have been able to know by looking at the `CONNECT` request issued by the client).
- If you're *not* after a MITM proxy, then you might as well let the initial connection through via your router. If you want to record that traffic, your router might be able to log the encrypted packets.

  Having your router catch the SSL/TLS packets to send them transparently to a proxy that will merely end up relaying that traffic untouched anyway to the target server doesn't make much sense. (By nature, the transparent proxy will imply the client isn't configured to know about it, so it won't even send its `CONNECT` method with which you could have had the requested host and port. Here, you'll really have nothing more than what the router can do.)

  **EDIT:** Once again, you simply *won't* be able to use an HTTP proxy to analyse the content of the connection transparently. Even when using a normal proxy, an HTTPS connection is relayed straight through to the target server. The SSL/TLS connection itself is established between the original client and the target server. The point of using SSL/TLS is to protect this connection, and to make the client notice if something is trying to look inside the connection.

  Plain HTTP transparent proxy servers work because (a) the traffic can be seen (in particular, the request line and the HTTP `Host` header are visible so that the proxy can know which request to make itself) and (b) the traffic can be altered transparently so that the initial client doesn't notice that the request wasn't direct and works as if it was.

  Neither of these conditions are true with HTTPS. HTTPS connections that go through an HTTP proxy are simply tunnel, after explicit request from the client, which has sent a `CONNECT` command and was configured to make use of such a proxy.

  To do something close to what you're after, you'd need an SSL/TLS server that accepts the SSL/TLS connection and deciphers it (perhaps something like STunnel) before your HTTP proxy. However, this won't be transparent, because it won't be able to generate the right certificates.

Comment: Thanks - I am not after a MITM in this case.  The 2nd proxy, however would serve as the MITM when forwarded.  Otherwise, yes, I would just relay it over the router.

What you mentioned is what I want to achieve, however I can't seem to do it using node-proxy.